# Cannot see content of a remote WordPress installation, but site loads

Tags: wordpress, xampp, remote-access

I am developing a WordPress-based website, and I have it successfully configured and running on my development machine using XAMPP. I can view the site remotely (from another physical location **EDIT: from another entirely different network -- NOT on the local network where the development machine resides**) but all of the content is still trying to use localhost as the source of linked files instead of the remote DNS address I have configured. Again, the site will load remotely, but it is all text with no CSS or images etc.

So basically this on the remote machine:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://localhost:8090/[...]/style.min.css?ver=5.3.2' media='all' />`

should look like this instead:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://my.dns.com:8090/[...]/style.min.css?ver=5.3.2' media='all' />`

I tried changing the "Site Address" (and WordPress Address, for that matter) to my DNS but that didn't help. Is there another setting or two that I am missing?

Comment: This may fix it. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263008/wordpress-incorrectly-redirects-to-local-ip-address

Comment: I forgot I had tried that, and unfortunately that also results in the same thing (content still referencing localhost).